# Team foundation server getting users of a project using Java SDK

Tags: java, tfs, tfs-sdk

i'm trying to get all the users that belong to a project through the SDK for Java version 11.0.0 but i'm stuck.
With that code i retrieve the collections and the projects:

```
TeamFoundationServerEntity teamFoundationServer=configurationServer.getTeamFoundationServerEntity(true);
if (teamFoundationServer != null)
{
        ProjectCollectionEntity[] projectCollections = teamFoundationServer.getProjectCollections();
        for (ProjectCollectionEntity pce : projectCollections) {
            System.out.println("Collection: "+pce.getDisplayName()+"  "+pce.getDescription());
            TeamProjectEntity[] tpe=pce.getTeamProjects();
            for (TeamProjectEntity teamProjectEntity : tpe) {
                System.out.println("    teamProjectEntity: "+teamProjectEntity.getDisplayName()+" * "+teamProjectEntity.getProjectURI());
            }
        }
}
```

Also with the following code taken from the example in the downloaded zip and has the groups information:

```
GUID[] resourceTypes = new GUID[]{
        CatalogResourceTypes.PROJECT_COLLECTION
    };
    CatalogResource[] resources =
        configurationServer.getCatalogService().queryResourcesByType(resourceTypes, CatalogQueryOptions.NONE);

    if (resources != null)
    {
        for (CatalogResource resource : resources)
        {
            String instanceId = resource.getProperties().get("InstanceId");
            TFSTeamProjectCollection tpc = configurationServer.getTeamProjectCollection(new GUID(instanceId));

            System.out.println("TFSTeamProjectCollection");
            System.out.println("\tName: " + tpc.getName().toString());
            System.out.println("\tURI: " + tpc.getBaseURI());

            ProjectCollection pc=tpc.getWorkItemClient().getProjects();

            for (Project project : pc) {
                System.out.println("---"+project.getName()+" * "+project.getID());

                String[] grps=tpc.getWorkItemClient().getGroupDataProvider(project.getName()).getGroups();
            }
       }
   }
```

I have found the class IdentityManagementService

```
IdentityManagementService ims=new IdentityManagementService(configurationServer);
```

but i don't know how to use the *listApplicationGroups* and *readIdentities* methods that maybe are useful to find a solution.
Has anyone some idea to get the users in every project group?

A few more trial after @Cece - MSFT answer and looking at the [blog](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/09/30/tfs-sdk-get-groups-users-permissions-using-tfs-api-with.aspx) and the book [Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Cookbook](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/microsoft-team-foundation/9781784391058/ch08s04.html). Using this code

```
TeamFoundationIdentity[] appGroups=ims.listApplicationGroups(project.getURI(), ReadIdentityOptions.EXTENDED_PROPERTIES);
for (TeamFoundationIdentity group : appGroups) 
{
    System.out.println(group.getDisplayName());
    TeamFoundationIdentity[] groupMembers= ims.readIdentities(new IdentityDescriptor[]{group.getDescriptor()}, MembershipQuery.EXPANDED, ReadIdentityOptions.EXTENDED_PROPERTIES);
    for (TeamFoundationIdentity member : groupMembers) 
    {
        for(IdentityDescriptor memberID : member.getMembers())
        {
            TeamFoundationIdentity memberInfo=ims.readIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.IDENTIFIER, memberID.getIdentifier(), MembershipQuery.EXPANDED, ReadIdentityOptions.EXTENDED_PROPERTIES);
            System.out.println(memberInfo.getDisplayName());
        }
    }
}
```

the variable *appGroups* is always empty. Maybe the method *project.getURI()* is not suitable? If I put *null*

```
TeamFoundationIdentity[] tfi=ims.listApplicationGroups(null, ReadIdentityOptions.INCLUDE_READ_FROM_SOURCE);
for (TeamFoundationIdentity teamFoundationIdentity : tfi) {
    System.out.println(teamFoundationIdentity.getDisplayName());
    System.out.println(teamFoundationIdentity.getDescriptor().getIdentityType());
    IdentityDescriptor[] mbs=teamFoundationIdentity.getMembers();
    for (IdentityDescriptor mb : mbs) {
        TeamFoundationIdentity mbi=ims.readIdentity(mb, MembershipQuery.EXPANDED, ReadIdentityOptions.EXTENDED_PROPERTIES);
        System.out.println(mbi.getProperties());
    }
}
```

the output is

```
[DefaultCollection]\Project Collection Administrators
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity
[DefaultCollection]\Project Collection Build Administrators
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity
[DefaultCollection]\Project Collection Build Service Accounts
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity
[DefaultCollection]\Project Collection Proxy Service Accounts
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity
[DefaultCollection]\Project Collection Service Accounts
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity
[DefaultCollection]\Project Collection Test Service Accounts
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity
[DefaultCollection]\Project Collection Valid Users
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity
```

Why I can't get the Contributors, Readers and the other groups with *project.getURI()* in *listApplicationGroups* method? I can only get them with

```
String[] grps=tpc.getWorkItemClient().getGroupDataProvider(project.getName()).getGroups();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is interested in this two link there is the answer:
[get groups of project](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1f880537-a89d-4707-a561-224eacaadba0/get-permissions-by-project-using-java-sdk?forum=tee) and [get members of a group](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/29dd8920-2389-4870-8447-5f073c40a595/get-members-of-a-group-with-java-sdk?forum=tee)

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/09/30/tfs-sdk-get-groups-users-permissions-using-tfs-api-with.aspx) blog. In this blog, author used `IGroupSecurityService` service to get the list of application groups and get the details of which group the user is a member.

But now, `IGroupSecurityService` is obsolete. You need to use the [IIdentityManagementService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.client.iidentitymanagementservice(v=vs.120).aspx) or `ISecurityService` instead.

The code snippet should look like:

```
var sec = tfs.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();
Identity[] appGroups = sec.ListApplicationGroups(Scope Uri);


foreach (Identity group in appGroups)
{
     Identity[] groupMembers = sec.ReadIdentities(SearchFactor.Sid, new string[] { group.Sid }, QueryMembership.Expanded);

     foreach (Identity member in groupMembers)
     {
         var groupM = new GroupMembership {GroupName = member.DisplayName, GroupSid = member.Sid};

         if (member.Members != null)
         {
             foreach (string memberSid in member.Members)
             {
                 Identity memberInfo = sec.ReadIdentity(SearchFactor.Sid, memberSid, QueryMembership.Expanded);

                 var userName = memberInfo.Domain + "\\" + memberInfo.AccountName;
```

Detailed steps, you can check the blog.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the questions providing more details.

Comment: Check IIdentityManagementService.ListApplicationGroups Method at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.client.iidentitymanagementservice.listapplicationgroups(v=vs.120).aspx, you need to use Scope Uri.

Comment: where I can find the project Scope URI?

Comment: Scope is a project URI or URL, including its GUID and connection string.The format is vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/ GUID.

Comment: I've printed _project.getURI()_ and _project.getGUID()_ and | obtain right what you've written. For example project Uri: vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/d5d1c7cc-63a1-4cf7-8491-0e237e92d291 and GUID: d5d1c7cc-63a1-4cf7-8491-0e237e92d291. Then why _listApplication_ method does not return something?